# ImageMagick incorrect dimensions

Tags: php, resize, imagemagick

I've been on this problem for several hours now. I can't crop/resize a certain image correctly.

The source image has a dimension of `900x398 px`
The target dimension is `650x178 px`

but the returned dimension is `647x178 px`. I dont't get it. This is the command I use:

```
/usr/bin/convert jpg:"/location/20-prefab_woningen.jpg" -auto-orient -shave 0x78 -resize 650x174 -colorspace RGB "location/new.jpg" &&exit
```

Is this a common bug? I can't find anything on the web about it. ImageMagick version doesn't seem to matter, tried both local and on the server but I get the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`resize` tries to *fit* the image into the specified dimensions. It doesn't force it to exactly that size. See the [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize).

Use the `!`flag to tell IM to ignore the aspect ratio.

```
/usr/bin/convert jpg:"/location/20-prefab_woningen.jpg" 
                -auto-orient -shave 0x78 
                -resize 650x174\! 
                -colorspace RGB "location/new.jpg" &&exit
```

Comment: Thnx, without the \ and with the ! it works perfectly. Thanks, your a lifesaver :)